# centos 8.0 yum cannot be found

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

I use Centos 8.0 and want to install the latest Python 3.

When I run `yum` command, it tells me

```
yum: command not found
```

but when I run `rpm -q yum`, I have it `yum-4.7.0-4.el8.noarch`.

Then I try to `which yum` I get

```
/usr/bin/which: no yum in (/root/.vscode-server/bin/xxx/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin)
```

This issue happened after I uninstalled an old Python version via

```
rpm -qa|grep python3|xargs rpm -ev --allmatches --nodeps
whereis python3 |xargs rm -frv
```

Would you mind giving me some advice on how to solve it?

Comment: Does `dnf`  or `sudo dnf` work? Yum was replaced with DNF in RHEL8 and its derivatives. No idea why the yum command is not available, probably a symlink has been deprecated. *"     The YUM package manager is now based on the DNF technology and it provides support for modular content, increased performance, and a well-designed stable API for integration with tooling."*

Comment: You must never run `rpm --nodeps` on your production system unless you're OK with your system malfunctioning right away or soon after. I use this command occasionally but I'm a pro user who perfectly knows what they are doing and only apply it the packages which I know for a fact will not break anything. It's best not to use RPM directly at all (though *generally* it must be safe).

Comment: `yum` is provided by the package `yum`. You'll need to run `sudo dnf install yum` to geT it back. Also, you do know that CentOS 8 reached end of life on 12/31/2022. You should think about moving to a supported OS.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> rpm -qa|grep python3|xargs rpm -ev --allmatches --nodeps
> ```

But with that you explicitly ask `rpm` to uninstall `python3-dnf`. What did you expect to happen?

You also disabled all safeguards by using `--nodeps`, because otherwise your system would have denied you to uninstall crucial parts.

Whatever it was that you were trying to achieve, you

1. explicitly uninstalled `dnf` and thus the virtual `yum` (which is just a symlink to `dnf`, because Centos 8 replaced yum with the largely compatible dnf)
2. broke your ability to install software on this system by uninstalling the package manager
3. uninstalled python3, which is essential to a CentOS system

So, you did this to yourself, sorry! You broke your system; it might be quite annoying to restore, because your dependency-breaking uninstallation of all python3 packages will have uninstalled quite a lot of things that you will need to figure out you need.

The easiest way forward here is probably rolling back from your backup, or in absence of a system backup, setting up a new CentOS 8.